# Maximum value of a direct fourier transform

Tags: python, fft, dft, spectrum

I have a list of samples of a wave with all values between `-1` and `+1`. Those values have been read from a music file. I will now,

1. apply the direct fourier transform, (`scipy.fftpack.rfft`)
2. normalize the values by dividing them by the square root of the number of samples,
3. calculate the power for each item in the list. (`sqrt(real^2 + imag^2)`)

**What are the maximum values I can expect to be in this list after all of this?** I would have expected the maximum power to be `1`, as the maximum amplitude in the input data is also `1`. However, this is only the case for a simple sine wave. As soon as I start doing this with real music, I get higher values.

How would I "normalize" the power to get values between `0`and `1`? Is it even possible to find out the maximum value? If not, what is the best practice to scale the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at a DC signal `1 1 1 1`, its DFT is `4 0 0 0`.

To normalize that back into [0,1], you need to divide by 4, i.e. the number of points.